# How to click on whole vuejs component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have component

and i want run method after click

```
<my-component @click="showOtherDiv"></my-component>
```

i have this method on main app methods

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {},

    methods: {
        showOtherDiv : function(){
            alert('Some message');
        }
    }
});
```

but seems like "click" not works on full component

Comment: It should work. Can you provide a codepen or jsfiddle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Register your component, and declare the handler method inside:

   ```js
    Vue.component('my-component', {
        // ...
        methods: {
            showOtherDiv : function(){
                alert('Some message');
            }
        }
    });
   ```
2. Add the `.native` modifier to the event name:

   ```html
    <my-component @click.native="showOtherDiv"></my-component>
   ```

   From [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events):

   > **Binding Native Events to Components**
   >
   > […] when you want to listen for a native event *on the root element of a component* […] you can use the `.native` modifier for `v-on`.